# Does not work properly move to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 buttons.

Three of them are showing licenses.
One of them entitled 'enterprise' has to go to another page.

Unfortunately when I click on the 'Enterprise' by moments shows the license and then page goes to another page.

How do I make does not pass on the code to display the license but immediately to another page?

My code:

```
$('input[title="enterprise"]').click(function(){
    window.location.href = "/contact";
});

$('input[type=button]').click(showLicence).each(function() {
    this.version = this.title;
    this.title = "Buy ";
    switch(this.version) {
        case 'basic':
            this.title += 'Basic';
            break;
        case 'standard':
            this.title += 'Standard';
            break;
        case 'business':
            this.title += 'Business';
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm no pro in javascript but doesn't this selector actually select all buttons : input[type=button]  ?

Answer (score 5):

Try using `:not`

```
$('input[type=button]:not([title="enterprise"])').click(showLicence).each(function() {
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your second event handler so that the `enterprise` button is excluded:

```
$('input[type=button]:not([title="enterprise"])').click(showLicence).each(function() {
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a unique class to separate the two functionality.

For eg :

```
<button class="enterprise">Enterprise</button>
<button class="normal">Basic</button>
<button class="normal">Standard</button>
<button class="normal">Business</button>
```

Then in JS, do a slight change :

```
$('.enterprise').click(function(){
    window.location.href = "/contact";
});

$('.normal').click(showLicence).each(function() {
    this.version = this.title;
    this.title = "Buy ";
    switch(this.version) {
        case 'basic':
            this.title += 'Basic';
            break;
        case 'standard':
            this.title += 'Standard';
            break;
        case 'business':
            this.title += 'Business';
            break;
    }
});
```

You can add all the attributes to the buttons as you want. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use 'default' switch keyword (or add a 'Enterprise' case):

```
$('input[type=button]').click(showLicence).each(function() {
this.version = this.title;
this.title = "Buy ";
switch(this.version) {
    case 'basic':
        this.title += 'Basic';
        break;
    case 'standard':
        this.title += 'Standard';
        break;
    case 'business':
        this.title += 'Business';
        break;
    default:
        window.location.href = "/contact";
}
```

});